# Access same class instance in multiple source files

Tags: c++, qt, class, opencv

I am working with opencv in Qt, doing some video recognition stuff for my thesis.

So i have a mainwindow(that shows the camera and and some sliders for the settings of the camera) and a dialog window which opens when by pressing a button with sliders for advanced settings. My problem is:
I create in instance of a class like

```
Moving M;
```

in mainwindow.cpp and i can set parameters like

```
M.BasicSetting1 = someValue;
```

But I cant access the M instance in another window (dialog), to set M.AdvencedSettings.

So where and how do I have to create an instance of class Moving to set its parameters in both mainwindow.cpp and dialog.cpp? I hope i was clear enough... Maybe if someone can just post a vary simple example of how to that. I appreciate your help very much!

---

Here is what I have (I wont be posting full codes because it will be easier this way (i hope that i wont have to :) )

```
Moving.h        //where my class is defined which accesses my webcam and stuff
mainwindow.h    //mainwindow where it shows the video with basicsettings
dialog.h        //some advanced settings for the webcam

main.cpp         
Moving.cpp
Mainwindow.cpp    
dialog.cpp
```

Moving.h

```
        class Moving
    {

    public:

int BasicSetting1;
int Basic Setting2;

int AdvancedSetting1;
int AdvancedSetting2;

    //lots of other stuff

    Moving();
    ~Moving();

    void move();  //starts and shows the camera

    };
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
      #include "Moving.h"
      #include "mainwindow.h"


        Moving M;

        M.BasicSetting1 = SliderValue; 

        M.move();  //shows camera



    //and of course lots of other stuff
```

Comment: `extern` may be the keyword you're looking for.

Comment: Assuming your Moving class is instancied in the MainWindow, you need to pass a pointer or reference to your Moving instance when the other dialogs are created (if they are created from the MainWindow, too). This way, you can avoid using a global variable. This is a case of dependency injection.

Comment: Really, it was that easy? extern did the trick! Thank you so very much, I spent 3 days trying to figure that out driving myself crazy!

Answer (score 4):

If I read your code correctly then you are creating the instance of `Moving` on the stack. Sharing pointers or references to stack objects can be dangerous. Instead you could declare `Moving` in your `mainwindow` and add a getter type method (i.e. `Moving* getMoving()`) to return an pointer to your `Moving` object. Then give your Dialog a pointer to the `mainwindow`.

All of this is very basic to the concept of programming. Maybe you should read some tutorials and do some other smaller stuff before writing your thesis; patching bad code can be very time-consuming.